# Laravel Many-to-Many relationship with recursive table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Many-to-Many relationship tables and one of the tables `codes` is recursive. My concern is, how to show the recursive table which is only part of relationship. I have no problem displaying this, but the issue was it shows all children.

```
    tables                  table_has_codes         codes
-----------------       -----------------       ----------------------
id  | name              table_id| code_id       id  | name | code_parent_id
-----------------       -----------------       ----------------------
1   | table_1               1   |   1           1   |   A  |    null
                            1   |   2           2   |   B  |    1
                            1   |   3           3   |   C  |    2
                                                4   |   D  |    3
-----------------   -----------------       --------------------------
```

So in model `Code`

```
public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'code_parent_id')->with('children');
    }
```

and my query is

```
Table::with('codes.children')
       ->whereId(1)
       ->first()
```

my expected result is

```
1 - A
1.1 - B
1.1.1 - C
```

but what I get

```
1 - A
1.1 - B
1.1.1 - C
1.1.1.1  - D
```

I know that there should be additional query here I just don't know how. I didn't include all the codes in the models but I think it's clear.

Comment: If I understood correctly, parent_id is referring to code.id, so, 2 can't be the parent of 2. It'll end with an infinite loop.

Comment: What is the expected result representing?

Comment: you want the codes that has a relation with tables?

Comment: post your code, *how do you query* & *how do you make relationship*

Comment: @TahaPaksu you are right. i updated the posts. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel using [Database Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database) you can achieve the expected output. Code will look like below.

```
DB::table('tables')
    ->join('table_has_codes', 'tables.id', 'table_has_codes.table_id')
    ->join('codes', 'table_has_codes.code_id', 'codes.id')
    ->select('codes.id as id', 'codes.name as name', 'codes.code_parent_id as parent_id')
    ->get();
```

But there is another alternative way as well. That's [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) check link for more information.

Comment: yep it will work but how about to make the result recursive?